# Error when casting variable

Tags: c#

I get an error when I try to cast a query. This is the code of the query:

```
var query = (from article in db.V_CLIENT_PRIX
                where article.CLIENT == Current_Client_Id
                   select new
                          {
                           ID = article.ID,
                           ARTICLE = article.Article,
                           REFERENCE = article.Reference,
                           REMISE = article.Remise,
                           PRIXVHT = article.PrixVHT,
                           CLIENT = article.CLIENT,
                          }
             );
```

And I cast it like this:

```
ConventionList articlelistconvention = new ConventionList();
articlelistconvention = (ConventionList)query;
```

This is the code of my `model:ConventionList`

```
public class Commandelist
{
    public string ARTICLE { get; set; }
    public string CIN { get; set; }
    public decimal STOCK { get; set; }
    public string REFERENCE { get; set; }
    public decimal PRIXVHT { get; set; }
    public string IMAGE { get; set; }
    public double QUANTITE { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: you can't cast one object to other if they are not at all related

Comment: Conventionlist or Commandelist? This cast wont work but you can instantiate a new instance of Commandelist and map the properties that match

Answer (score 2):

You might be coming from a language with duck typing, like Javascript; however, in C# this is not possible. You can typically only cast objects if the interfaces and/or inheritance allows you to do so. The dynamic object you create in your Linq query will not share ancestry with the object you're trying to cast to.

In your specific code example though there is a quick fix:

```
var query = (
     from article in db.V_CLIENT_PRIX
     where article.CLIENT == Current_Client_Id
     select new ConventionList                          // < --- change here!!
     {
         ID = article.ID,
         ARTICLE = article.Article,
         REFERENCE = article.Reference,
         REMISE = article.Remise,
         PRIXVHT = article.PrixVHT,
         CLIENT = article.CLIENT,
     });
```

However, getting this to work exactly for your scenario might require some tweaking, as your question is ambiguous about the difference / overlap between the dynamic object, the `ConventionList` class, and the `CommandeList` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your type in the SELECT.

1. You can't cast anonymous types to declared types
2. You can't cast unrelated types to each other (`command` / `convention`) unless you just slopely pasted the wrong code for us to look at / figure out)
3. You can't cast `List<T>` of one type to another type, IEnemurable could work if the generics were related because of covariance.

Updated code with an explicit type in the constructor instead of an anonymous object, again I think you meant Convention but if not change it to the type you need.

```
var query = (
    from article in db.V_CLIENT_PRIX
    where article.CLIENT == Current_Client_Id
    select new Convention()
    {
     ID = article.ID,
     ARTICLE = article.Article,
     REFERENCE = article.Reference,
     REMISE = article.Remise,
     PRIXVHT = article.PrixVHT,
     CLIENT = article.CLIENT,
    });
```